# PCA plot not showing all data points

Tags: r, plot, pca

I have some data that looks like this:

```
               Cluster_ID       KO1      KO2      KO3       WT1       WT2      WT3
  5  chr5:100947454..100947489,+   3.31322  7.52365  3.67255  21.15730  8.732710 17.42640
 12 chr5:101227760..101227782,+   1.48223  3.76182  5.11534  15.71680  4.426170 13.43560
 29 chr5:102236093..102236457,+  15.60700 10.38260 12.46040   6.85094 15.551400  7.18341
```

I have filtered it as follows:

```
data<-read.table("expresn_matrix.txt", header=T)
CAGE_data <- as.data.frame(data) # Check that it has been converted to 

#Remove clusters with 0 expression for all 6 samples
CAGE_filter <- CAGE[rowSums(abs(CAGE[,2:7]))>0,]

#Filter whole file to keep only clusters with at least 5 TPM in at least 3 files
CAGE_filter_more <- CAGE_filter[apply(CAGE_filter[,2:7] >= 5,1,sum) >= 3,]

CAGE_data <- as.data.frame(CAGE_filter_more)
CAGE_datam <- t(as.matrix(CAGE_data))
CAGE_data[, c(2:7)] <- sapply(CAGE_data[, c(2:7)], as.numeric)
rm= rowMeans(CAGE_data[, c(2:7)])

#Get data dimensions
dim(CAGE_datam)
```

After filtering, the data dimensions are:

```
 [1]   7 599
```

I do PCA on the data:

```
pca<-prcomp(t(CAGE_data[,2:7]), scale.=TRUE) 
summary(pca)$importance[,1:6]
cols <- gsub(pattern="(\\w+)\\d+", replacement="\\1",    x=colnames(CAGE_data[,2:7]))

qplot(PC1, PC2, label=colnames(CAGE_data[,2:7]), color=cols, geom=c("point", "text"),
  data=as.data.frame(pca$x))
```

My plot only has 6 points, for each sample. It needs to be concentrated with many more points. I am not sure why there are are only 6 points, when I have 599 rows of data from 6 samples? Can someone please help me?

Thank you.

Comment: maybe I'm missing something here but 6 samples => 6 points so I don't really see what the problem is (maybe you can ask @espop23 as you seem to work on the same data... ? see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32267418/changing-pca-plot-to-have-2-colors-instead-of-6))

Comment: There are 6 samples of points from 598 chromosomes. I have clustered the data so there should be more points

Comment: not with the code you provided. you're plotting your 6 samples (6 points) according to the PC1 and PC2, which are constructed from the 598(or 599?) variables (chromosomes it seems). (also, I don't really understand what you mean by "clustered" because, usually, when you create clusters, you end up with less groups than you had points)

Comment: My data is a (biologically) sequenced expression matrix that contains cluster names and their expression in each sample normalized in TPM (tags per million). At the start I had 6981 clusters, after filtering to have 0 TPM, there were 6956, and after the final filtering there are 599 clusters. I want to plot to see how the different samples cluster. The plot I have doesnt show the variance as expected, since there are 599 data points to be shown.